# c++ interesting syntax for printing new line in std::cout

Tags: c++, arrays, pointer-arithmetic

the following code prints a square of `'*'` characters:

```
int m = 5; int n=5;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        std::cout << "*" << " \n"[j==5];
```

Output:

```
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
```

My question is regarding to the  `" \n"[j==5]` part.
Does anyone know how exactly does this syntax work?

Comment: `" \n"` is an array of 3 `char`, and `[j==5]` is an indexing operator accessing either first or second array item.

Comment: It's just an array of two (or more) characters indexed by a boolean value.

Comment: The three chars in " \n" are { ' ', '\n', '\0' }

Comment: Code like this should never be written. If it isn't obvious what it does then it's bad code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`" \n"` is array of 3 `char`s. You can index is as normal array. Boolean values implicitly convert to integers: `false` to `0`, `true` to `1`. So it will use `'\n'` for `j == 5` and `' '` if not,

Comment: I might be really confused with something... but isn't " \n" an array of only two chars? i.e: ' ' is the first char and '\n' the second one?

Comment: @NicoBerrogorry String literals always end with '\0' in C and C++

Comment: Dah. My bad, I didn't think of that. Maybe because of how std::string is implemented. Thanks!